# Can the ball on a turn coordinator be to the full right/left while the wings are level?

Tags: aerodynamics

Can it ever happen in a wings level flight that the Turn and Slip indicator ball is to the full right/left? If so then when and what will be the flight path of such an aircraft? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [Are the functions of ailerons and rudder similar](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24101/are-the-functions-of-ailerons-and-rudder-similar?noredirect=1&lq=1)? which shows a wing level skidding turn with ball deflected. Note that in that case, while the wing is level, the turn indicator shows the turn rate to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when the rudder is highly deflected. The slip indicator gives us information on the [yaw axis of the airplane](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/18994/whats-the-purpose-of-yawing) and "level flight" is generally in relation to a neutral pitch and power situation (i.e. not climbing or descending). An aircraft can be yawed with rudder input alone and subsequently cause the slip ball to deflect as appropriate.

Comment: When you typed "yaw access", was that a typo for "axis" or "angle" or something else? (Someone else edited it to "axis".)

Comment: @TannerSwett my mistake axis is correct

Comment: Fun fact: on a twin flying on one engine, the rudder applied to counteract the yawing moment of the live engine redirects the net thrust line toward the dead engine and if you keep wings level you are actually slewing to the right.  You bank into the live engine about 5 deg to create an opposing side slip force, which cancels out the slew to the right.  You end up flying along straight through the air, tilted toward the live engine, with the skid ball offset toward the live engine about a ball width (but aligned with the true vertical axis), in coordinated flight.